# keep apostrophes when passing string value in Innerhtml

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

The text value holds string text with double quotes and apostrophes as you see in the example. when I print the result it changes to different characters.

**The text that is coming from API is :**

"mismatched input 'STARTt' expecting 'START' ";

**but when I print it, it goes :**

"mismatched" input="" 'startt'="" expecting="" 'start'=""

I would like to print the string exactly how is stored

```js
  
  var marker = document.createElement("div");
  
  var text = "mismatched input 'STARTt' expecting 'START' ";
  
  marker.innerHTML = "<div data-tooltip=" + text+ ">⚠️</div>";



console.log(marker.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute values containing spaces have to be delimited with `"` or `'`.

Attribute values containing `'` have to be delimited with `"`

Attribute values containing `"` have to be delimited with `'`.

Attribute values containing `"` and `'` have to be delimited with one of those while the other has to be replaced with the appropriate entity (`&quot;` or `&apos;`).

---

Trying to generate HTML by mashing strings together is asking for trouble when you hit any kind of escaping requirements.

Don't do it. Use DOM methods instead.

```js
const marker = document.createElement("div");
const text = "mismatched input 'STARTt' expecting 'START' ";
const child = document.createElement('div');
child.setAttribute('data-tooltip', text);
child.innerText = "⚠️";
marker.appendChild(child);
console.log(marker.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap `text` with quotes.

This works for me:

`marker.innerHTML = "<div data-tooltip=\"" + text+ "\">⚠️</div>";`

Answer (score -2):

Use a template string. It should solve the problem

```
  var marker = document.createElement("div");
  
  var text = `mismatched input 'STARTt' expecting 'START' `;
  
  marker.innerHTML = `<div data-tooltip=" + text+ ">⚠️</div>`;



console.log(marker.innerHTML);
```

Comment: It won't solve the problem. You now just have a different problem.